# Avoid spaces getting converted to tabs automatically during shift(>>)

Tags: tab-characters, whitespace

I use 2 spaces as indentation. So I set `shiftwidth` using `:set sw=2`.

However when I do the shift operator(`>>`) on a line twice, the indentation converts the 4 spaces automatically to a tab. So to avoid this, I set `tabstop` to a high value say 60 using `:set ts=60` and the shift operator works (does NOT convert space to tab).

My question is, Is this the right way to do? Am I missing a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `'expandtab'` option setting. This will prevent shifting from replacing indent by using TABs.

Answer (score 0):

I have two functions that swap back and forth between tabs and spaces, as well, if interested.

```
function! Tabstyle_tabs()
  " Default to using 8 column tabs
  set softtabstop=8
  set shiftwidth=8
  set tabstop=8
  set noexpandtab
endfunction

function! Tabstyle_spaces()
  " Default to using 4 column indents
  set softtabstop=4
  set shiftwidth=4
  set tabstop=4
  set expandtab
endfunction
```

You can set the `8` and `4` to whatever sizes you like of course.
I'd started to work on a function that takes variable size tabstop, but haven't bothered, as I use `autocmds` for different file types and this use these functions only when necessary otherwise.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need to set `shiftwidth` and `softtabstop` in your functions. If you `:set shiftwidth=0 softtabstop=-1` then they will both use the value of `tabstop`.

Answer (score 0):

The [YAIFA plugin](https://github.com/Raimondi/YAIFA) may be of interest.

It tries to auto-detect the indentation method used in the current file, and set your `expandtab` `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` options appropriately.